# What is the official stance behind comments that copy a close reason verbatim?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I've seen comments that read like this:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

This is transcribed *verbatim* from the close reason itself.

Should these comments be left alive?  I've been flagging them as "not constructive".  Would that be an appropriate flag reason?

Comment: They're no longer useful once the OP sees them, or if the question gets closed with that very reason (in which case the comment becomes redundant).

Comment: I don't disagree with that sentiment, but "no longer useful" implies that they're useful at all.  I'm not so sure I see value in the comments; while putting a question on hold is a good reminder to the OP, the comment alone comes across as snide.

Comment: Related to this is the question of "why are comments auto-generated on my behalf when I type in a custom off-topic closure reason?" Just today, I had someone [complain that I was a "keyboardwarrior"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781941/how-to-get-my-photoshop-pixelbar-back?noredirect=1#comment40322853_25781941) (whatever that is) in response to an auto-generated close comment. One wonders what the purpose of those are. If the community doesn't agree with me and the question never gets closed, then my voice doesn't really matter. And if they do, it's redundant.

Comment: @CodyGray about "keyboardwarrior" Bart says [is this](http://www.kumah.org/uploaded_images/KeyboardWarrior-758095.jpg)

Comment: *So* tempted to copy a verbatim close reason into a comment on this question...

Comment: @AirThomas:  You'd only be proving my point of them being less than useful.  Besides, I wouldn't even know what message you'd be able to reasonably use.

Comment: @Makoto Are you trying to indirectly talk to me? (I'm one of those people who leave comments like those, by the way.)

Comment: @Makoto "This question appears to be off topic because it lacks freehand circles, or the freehand circles in the question are not red. Please refer to [the Meta.SE style guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121722/254929) for help formatting your post."

Comment: "This question **does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community**. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail."

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi:  If you're one of the folks that does that, then perhaps I am talking to you.  I wasn't calling anyone in particular out, though.  I suppose my question is, "what is the real value in that comment?"  To me, it adds unnecessary noise, and can come across as quite hostile.

Comment: @AirThomas I know of a program that automatically converts freehand-drawn shapes into actual shapes, using a tool called the Shape Recognition Tool.

Comment: @Makoto Whenever I leave such a comment, I always remember to always cast a recommend closure flag (I don't yet have enough rep to cast close votes). There hasn't ever been a single instance in which such flags have been declined in review.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Once the question is closed (presumably for that reason) I'd flag the comment as obsolete. If the question *should* be closed for that reason but isn't, I'd leave the comment alone. It serves to educate the OP until the official close reason is in place. If the commenter is just way off base and the question is unlikely to be closed at all, go ahead and flag the comment as not constructive.

Comment: Tone matters. If the commenter comes off as a jerk, I'll delete the comment if it's flagged as such.

Comment: Personally, I don't understand why such a comment isn't publish automatically, like that's done when we review "Low Quality Posts". That's really educating for the OP, which should otherwise wait for the question to be closed to understand why he was (probably) down-voted or not-answered. And that can take a long time.