# Why not always comment automatically why a question should be closed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If I vote to close a question because it is a duplicate, it will add a comment to the question saying it might be a duplicate, with the link to the other/original question. This is awesome.

But if I click on close and then choose *off-topic because...* and there I choose this:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must
>   include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the
>   shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**.
>   Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other
>   readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Why isn't that inserted as a comment?

Wouldn't it be useful information to the user writing the question?

Comment: The dupe is useful for the OP as that might instantly answer their question. For the other close reasons it is to be seen if that single close voter made the right judgement call. That is why it is not advertized in a comment so the question gets a kind-of unbiased view.

Comment: @rene thanks for your comment, that makes sense. Just thinking about how to prevent stuff like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302658/how-to-copy-different-input-from-a-textbox-to-different-fields-using-javascript `5 downvotes`, `1 closure (mine with the above mentioned text)` and one comment with 3 upvotes saying to read How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example.

Comment: It needs 3K-ers who are prepared to use their close vote privilege. There are enough 3K-ers but it seems not everyone wants to use their privilege to the full extent. Solving that is the holy grail of moderation.

Comment: @rene thanks again! I didn't know that with the 3K-ers, that makes sense! So what about my question here, should I leave it or remove it?

Comment: I expect this to be a duplicate but I can't find one. Your question is clear enough so even if I find a dupe it would still be useful to have around so no reason to delete it. Your question has value.

Comment: If you want to always post that as a comment when you vtc as off topic, go over to stackapps and find my Always Be Closing script.  You can modify the off-topic close reason to be anything you want (at line 32 in the gist).

Comment: There's no reason to have the system automatically post a comment in this situation.  If we want the OP to actually see the close reason(s) before the question is closed just do what duplicates do and show the OP an altered banner when there are pending close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively you're espousing the idea that repeating the information that will *eventually* be available to the OP for why their question is closed is somehow...helpful.  Personally, I don't think it is, and [it can even be seen as noise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271212/1079354) if it's left in there after the fact.

Admittedly this means that the feedback loop takes a little longer, since it may mean that their question may get closed for being incomplete, but the idea is that we want OPs to ask questions with complete details.  Those that do come back and edit the details in have a chance of getting their question reopened, and those that don't have the close reason as to why it was closed right there.

Comment: More specifically, their question can be closed without ever notifying them at all in any way; if they naively suppose that they can fire and forget because comments, answers, or anything else that actually needs their attention will send a notification, they may get an unpleasant surprise if they ever do check back.